# Xenforo image and attachement URL after Migration

Tags: xenforo

I recently migrated Xenforo forum from Amazon AWS to Linode. I also moved all attachments and images and saved them on my server path /var/www/html/data/attachments. When I view forum images on the new server, their URLs still point back to AWS S3. I want them to point to the attachments folder on new domain, i.e http://my-new-domain/var/www/html/data/attachmments.

Answer (score 0):

From the Xenforo [manual](https://xenforo.com/xf2-docs/manual/config/) regarding config.php options:

```
If you want to change the location that XenForo stores the data and scripts it keeps in files, such as avatars, attachments and javascript files, you can do so by altering these settings.

$config['externalDataPath'] = 'data';
$config['externalDataUrl'] = 'data';
$config['internalDataPath'] = 'internal_data';

internalDataPath
Defines the path to the 'internal_data' directory, which contains files that are not served directly to web browser clients, such as attachments.
```

You will want to checkout the config.php and see if any non-standard options are set such as externalDataUrl or externalDataPath.

Check your redirects and make sure you didn't make a redirect in the past your forgot about